# MYSQL Access denied for root when importing table

Tags: php, html, mysql, exec

Using my browser with a php script to import a table. Here is my code which ouputs 
*Enter password: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)*

```
<?php

echo "Starting update<br>";
echo exec("mysql -u root -pMYPASSWORD mydatabase < table1.sql 2>&1",$var1,$var2);

echo "<BR><BR>";
foreach ($var1 as $line)
{
echo $line . "<BR>";
}

echo "<BR><BR>";
foreach ($var2 as $line)
{
echo $line . "<BR>";
}

?>
```

Note, I am running on a VPS hosted by Bluehost. MySQL version 5.6. When I use php mysql commands, I am able to use the root login just fine.

Per bluehost's instructions:

*To import a single table into an existing database you would use the following command:
mysql -u username -p -D database_name < tableName.sql*

As you can see, they do not enter a password after -p, but I've also tried that to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: @Rimas Tried that too. Both with and without space. No work :/

Comment: You are right, there must be no space: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html#option_general_password

Comment: You either have no space on your mysql engine OR using the wrong password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, figured it out. Looks like Bluehost sets your "root" login to your user name on your account. So my user name should replace "root" and it works!

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you add `-h127.0.0.1` i guess

Comment: Nope. Sorry. Also, the error is already saying it's @localhost if you read my first few lines.

Comment: localhost and 127.0.0.1 are not the same when you use mysql. If you  use localhost it will try to use the unix socket instead of tcp to connect to mysqld. But you already figured it out anyway. I'm wondering how you could connect from php then?